# C# .NET 4.0 Drag and drop between two applications

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop

So I'd really like to drag and drop data between two instances of an application; however, if there is data present at the target point where I am dropping, I would like to swap that data with what is being dropped.

I'm trying to use a MemoryMappedFIle, and that seems to work most of the time, but it's not perfect. For example, if I do the drag / drop too quickly, the target data is simply overwritten (I assume it's not being written to the MemoryMappedFile quickly enough). Does anyone have any recommendations?﻿

This is what I currently have:

```
    private void pbSprite_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)(sender);
        DataObject data = new DataObject();
        if (pb.Name == pbSprite.Name)
        {
            data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, frmpkm);
        }
        else
        {
            data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, frmpkm2);
        }
        pb.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Move);
        MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("name", 1000, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor FileMap = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            PKMDS.Pokemon otherpkm = new PKMDS.Pokemon();
            for (int i = 0; i < Marshal.SizeOf(otherpkm); i++)
            {
                FileMap.Read<byte>(i, out otherpkm.Data[i]);
            }
            if (pb.Name == pbSprite.Name)
            {
                frmpkm.Data = otherpkm.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                frmpkm2.Data = otherpkm.Data;
            }
            lblData.Text = frmpkm.SpeciesName;
            lblData2.Text = frmpkm2.SpeciesName;
            pbSprite.Image = frmpkm.Sprite;
            pbSprite2.Image = frmpkm2.Sprite;
        }
    }
    private void pbSprite_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)(sender);
            PKMDS.Pokemon otherpkm = (PKMDS.Pokemon)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
            MemoryMappedFile MemoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("name", 1000, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
            using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor FileMap = MemoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Marshal.SizeOf(frmpkm); i++)
                {
                    if (pb.Name == pbSprite.Name)
                    {
                        FileMap.Write<byte>(i, ref frmpkm.Data[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileMap.Write<byte>(i, ref frmpkm2.Data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pb.Name == pbSprite.Name)
            {
                frmpkm.Data = otherpkm.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                frmpkm2.Data = otherpkm.Data;
            }
            lblData.Text = frmpkm.SpeciesName;
            lblData2.Text = frmpkm2.SpeciesName;
            pbSprite.Image = frmpkm.Sprite;
            pbSprite2.Image = frmpkm2.Sprite;
        }
    }
```

Comment: An MMF is a *very* low-level interop object.  You must always add your own synchronization to handshake with whatever other code is accessing the MMF.  It goes wrong in your program because you don't have any, you never made sure that the last data you wrote was read.  So don't use an MMF, there's in general very little point to it in managed code, use a named pipe instead or socket instead.  Or WCF, made to make this easy.  Or just plain Drag+Drop, already made to copy data across process boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible things to try

Move the call to `pb.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Move);` after the creation of the memory mapped file. This will cause a delay in the start of the drag/drop action but should ensure that the data has been written to the file.

The other alternative is to write the data to the mmf in a separate thread and have it set and Event when the data is written. Then `pbSprite_DragDrop` can wait for the event to be signaled before reading from the file.